# Top 15 query in sql server with criteria

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to convert a query from access to SQL Server but it take so much time in Sql 
server vs Access

I'm Trying to get last(desc) top 15 history article for every article.

```
SELECT *
FROM HistoryArticle INNER JOIN Articles ON HistoryArticle.[No article] = Articles .[No article]
WHERE (((HistoryArticle.NoHistory) In (select top 15 NoHistory from HistoryArticle where  HistoryArticle.[no article]=articles.[no article] order by NoHistory desc)))
ORDER BY HistoryArticle.NoHistory DESC;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

something like this probably runs faster:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    RANK OVER(ORDER BY HistoryArticle.[No article] DESC) HistRank
          FROM      HistoryArticle
                    INNER JOIN Articles ON HistoryArticle.[No article] = Articles.[No article]
        ) X
WHERE   HistRank <= 15
ORDER BY HistRank
```